# MEDIA_URL images not showing on template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make images show in my templates when I deploy them in heroku, the problem is that when I upload the image via the admin page, the image link is `/media/media/images/8734HDFJ93.jpeg` , notice that there are two `media`'s directories. The image shows fine when I click on the link, but it doesn't show in my templates. The way I'm trying to get the images in my templates is by doing

```
<img src="/{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ myobject_instance.image }}">
```

I have a model that has an image field as follows

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/images", blank=True)
```

and I have these urls in my urls.py

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
```

and in my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'site_media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double media in your HTML because `upload_to` appends to the MEDIA_ROOT / MEDIA_URL. Since you have "media/images" in the `upload_to` this makes it appear twice. If you want to get rid of it, just make `upload_to` as "images" and don't forget to move the directory if you want to see already uploaded images.

Second being that your template has a slight issue:

```
<img src="/{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ myobject_instance.image }}">
```

should be:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ myobject_instance.image }}">
```

The initial / will makes it an url that Django won't find. You'll get "//media/media/images/8734HDFJ93.jpeg" instead of "/media/media/images/8734HDFJ93.jpeg"

Answer (score 0):

If you do inspect element in your rendered page, you will see the URL which is generated for the image. Instead of using the variable of "MEDIA_URL", you can use this template function:

```
{% get_media_prefix %}
```

So, finally it would be something like this:

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ myobject_instance.image }}">
```

Don't forget to include this line at the beginning of your template file:

```
{% load static %}
```